# VBA in Excel v2010 - Select Case command within another Select Case

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a Excel v2010 Project I'm trying to complete, and I'm trying to use the "Select Case" command within another "Select Case" .... at the moment it doesn't seem to work... so my question is.. can it actually work and I'm doing it wrong or should I replace it with "if-else-end if" ??

```
  Select Case LCase(Cells(i, "B").Value)

         Case LCase("ABC")

         Select Case LCase(Cells(i, "C").Value)
                    Case "DEF"
                         x = x + 1
```

Thanks Guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. Read [this article](http://www.excelvbasql.com/VBATutorialInfo.aspx?id=61).

Actually, your code doesn't work, because `LCase` returns lower case, but your `Case "DEF"` is in upper case, so you need to slightly modify your code:

```
Select Case LCase(Cells(i, "C").Value)
       Case "def"
```